# To which CPUs can I upgrade my Dell XPS M1330 laptop?

Tags: cpu, upgrade, dell-xps

I've got a Dell XPS M1330 laptop which is already a couple of years old. I've already upgraded to 8GB of RAM and a SDD.
Since I do all my development work (under Ubuntu) on this machine, I'd like to get more performance out of it. Currently, the bottleneck seems to be CPU.

The BIOS version (sudo dmidecode -s bios-version) is A15.
Hwinfo says the CPU now is a

6.15.13 "Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5550  @ 1.83GHz"

I know I'll probably have to look for an upgrade on eBay or similar, but I can handle the installation myself.

The question is: Which models of CPU can I use without changing motherboard or other big renovations ? More cores would be my priority. Or how can I find this out myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is a socket P motherboard

T8100
T8300
T9300

will work.

[Source of Information](http://en.community.dell.com/what-do-i-buy/f/3510/t/19206664.aspx)

.

> Originally, it could only be configured with Intel Core 2 Duo mobile processors up to T7700 (2.4 GHz), but could later be configured with processors up to the Intel Core 2 Duo T9500. The XPS M1330

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_XPS#XPS_M1330)

.

Comment: dots are much faster for me.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and especially the sources. I actually looked at the wiki article before but must have missed that part...

Two follow-ups, though:
1) Is there a chance of getting more cores ?
2) Do I have to check for things like the Bus speed, or will that "just work" ?

Comment: I would stick to the recommended processors, they should work without issue.